# PHP: Can I output for download a GZ archive on the fly?

Tags: php, gzip

I have an input file, some processing and then I need to be able to output it as raw file or GZ.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $this->generate_file_name() . '"');

while (!feof()) {
    $line = some_processing(line_of_file);
    echo $line;
}
```

I am working with large files, so it is not an option to save the whole file on the server and then compress it with gzcompress(). I need to do that on the fly - echo $line.
Is there a way?

I tried passing every line to gzencode(), but I can't uncompress the file after that.

Comment: Compressed data formats are not line-based.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can generate it fully valid (eg.: each part is a part not a complete file), you can deliver it in as many parts as you need/want.

Comment: I know that but it doesn't really help :)
Some example, some functions to look at?

Comment: If you don't have something already, try studying somethig like this: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/3191.html or this: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/1967.html